# How to make two \lstinputlisting in one listing

Tags: listings

In the following document:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{float}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\fontsize{7}{8}\ttfamily},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[language=Java,caption={A simple Java method}, label={lst:defectExample}, captionpos=b]{./CodeSnippets/DefectExample.java}

    \lstinputlisting[language=Java,caption={Testing the method}, label={lst:defectExample}, captionpos=b]{./CodeSnippets/DefectExampleTest.java}
\end{document}
```

How can make the two `lstinputlisting` in one listing and each one has its own caption? I tried adding them in `\begin{listing} \end{listing}` but gave me an error `Environment listing undefined. \begin{listing}`.

Can someone help me fixing this?

Comment: The environment defined by the `listings` package is called `lstlisting`.

Comment: @leandriis That didn't solve the problem. I want the two `lstinputlisting` in one listing.